# Referencing to a theorem using \cite and memoir

Tags: citing, memoir

I am citing a book, and I would like to reference a specific theorem within that book. Usually, I would use something like

> \cite[Theorem~4]{Reference}

which would have produced something like [1, Theorem 4] as an output. However I am using the `memoir` document class, and when I try to do that I get the following error:

> ! Argument of \@citex has an extra }.

Is there any way to circumvent this without too much pain?

(Removing the [Theorem~4] part from the code works just fine.)

Comment: (1) welcome, (2)  please provide a full minimal example so we get a better clue of what you are doing. Memoir has no problem with the syntax you provide, so something else must be wrong. To figure it out we need more information

Comment: If this is in the optional argument to a theorem-like environment, you should protect it with braces: `\begin{thm}[{\cite[Theorem~4]{key}}]`

Comment: @egreg: That solved it! If you post it as an answer, I will accept.

Comment: It's a duplicate; don't worry: searching the site is difficult even for regulars.